# Flask returning 505 “Broken Pipe” on Abyss Web Server

Tags: python, windows, flask

I have written a simple script which I am trying to "deploy" on the Abyss Web Server. I have followed the instructions on [Aprelium website](https://aprelium.com/abyssws/python.html). However when I try and access the 'app' a 500 (internal server error) is returned.

The error was logged by the server:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[14/Nov/2017:19:44:12 +0000]    CGI: [(path)\dev\Python\Scripts\python.exe yourapplication.py ] URI: /dev/Python/yourapplication.py Broken pipe
```

I also tried following the instructions on the [Flask Site](https://aprelium.com/abyssws/python.html) however these instructions relate to Linux and they document using command line so I am not even sure I was using WSGI or CGI correctly.

This is my script if it helps:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

app.run()
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I usually see broken pipe when I try to reload an older page. Did you try accessing the link from a new browser window?

Comment: @brokenfoot  Yeah  I did unfortunately it's not that.

Comment: The problem is with your underlying tcp connection. You can use `netstat` on windows to check if server is listening on port 5000. Also, from client, when you access the server, check `netstat` on client, you should see something like (`lsof` output from linux, similar tool to `netstat`): `python          54369   343783    4u  IPv4 194465244      0t0  TCP 10.30.218.211:5000->10.24.62.245:57825 (ESTABLISHED)`

Comment: @brokenfoot  As far as I can tell I am getting Local Address `192.168.0.4:8000`.  Foreign Address `Simon 65425` State `Time_Wait`. And it seems nothing is being server on port 5000.  Also my server uses port 8000 if that makes any difference.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if what I did was right but I got the same results over and over.

Comment: Time wait means connection is closing.. try from different browser, new window to see the state of the new connection using same commands. https://superuser.com/a/173542

Comment: I ran it in edge.  A different message appeared:  Local Address: `192.168.0.4:8000`, Foreign Address: `Simon:8000`, State: `Close_Wait`.  I'll try another browser.

Comment: In Firefox:  `192.168.0.4:63278`, `Simon:8000`, `ESTABLISHED`.  It still returned the error.

Comment: @brokenfoot  I don't know if you read the above?